# gracefull fallback where one promise in async / await chain fails?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

So, I've got a chain of api calls that I need to perform, something like this

```
const myBigCall = async (paramsObj) => {
  try {
    const data1 = await myCall1(paramsObj.first);
    const data2 = await myCall2(paramsObj.second);
    const data3 = await myCall3(paramsObj.third);
  } catch e { console.error(e) }
}
```

in this case `data1`, `data2`, `data3` are unrelated, yet have to be done within 1 function like this. This means if one of these requests fails, application will be partially erred, but still can show other data. Right now if `data1` or `data2` fail `data3` will never be called. Is there a way to call it, yet still be able to catch errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the calls are unrelated, you shouldn't use await that way as it will block every call. At the very least, you should use Promise.all to make the calls simultaneously.

```
const myBigCall = async (paramsObj) => {
  try {
    const dataArray = await Promise.all([
        myCall1(paramsObj.first),
        myCall2(paramsObj.second),
        myCall3(paramsObj.third)
    ]);
  } catch e { console.error(e) }
};
```

However, that will still fail if one of the promises fail. An easy way to get out of it would be to create a wrapper function that will prevent the fail and return `null` or `undefined` in case of fail and remove the whole try block:

```
const dontFail = promise => promise.catch(() => null);

const myBigCall = async (paramsObj) => {
  const dataArray = await Promise.all([
      myCall1(paramsObj.first),
      myCall2(paramsObj.second),
      myCall3(paramsObj.third)
  ].map(dontFail));

}
```